# PandasのDataFrameのplotメソッドで、同軸グラフの表示順を指定したい

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

PandasのDataFrameのplotメソッドで、折れ線グラフに、追加で横棒グラフを表示させたいのですが、
表示順(zorder)の指定ができず困っています。（現状は棒グラフを半透明色にしてごまかしています。）
棒グラフを最背面へ、凡例を最前面へ表示を指定することは可能でしょうか？

```
# zorderが効かない例(pd.DataFrameのplotメソッドを利用)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'value':[ 100, 200, 300, 200 ] }, index=[ 10, 20, 30, 40 ])
ax = df.plot(zorder=2)

x = [ 100, 200, 300 ]
y = [ 20, 25, 30 ]
twin_ax = ax.twiny()
twin_ax.barh(x, y, color='#00ff00', height=50, zorder=1) # 横棒グラフ
plt.show() # 描画
```

[image: 表示順が指定できない例]

以下は、他サイトで調べたうまくいく例です。
matplotlibを直接利用しないと表示順(zorder)は指定できないものなのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
# zorderが有効な例(matplotlibを直接利用)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [ 100, 200, 300 ]
y = [ 20, 25, 30 ]
plt.plot(x, y, zorder=2, color='r')
plt.scatter(x, y, zorder=1, s=200)
plt.show() # 描画
```

Comment: twiny()は必須ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_zorder](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_zorder.html) で ax 自体の `z_order` を変更してみました。

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'value':[ 100, 200, 300, 200 ] }, index=[ 10, 20, 30, 40 ])
ax = df.plot()

x = [ 100, 200, 300 ]
y = [ 20, 25, 30 ]
twin_ax = ax.twiny()
twin_ax.barh(x, y, color='#00ff00', height=50) # 横棒グラフ

ax.set_zorder(2)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
twin_ax.set_zorder(1)

plt.show() # 描画
```

[image: z_order]

Comment: ax.set_zorder()メソッド、
およびax.patch.set_alpha(0)
で表示順を変更できました。
解決しました。ありがとうございました。